# php website game pokemon

Tags: php, mysqli

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\PTT\forum-categories.php on line 181
>   Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location  
1   0.0000  273632  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0  
2   0.0127  612320  include( 'C:\wamp\www\PTT\forum-categories.php' )   ..\index.php:219
3   0.0156  617456  mysqli_query ( )    ..\forum-categories.php:181**
```

Line 181 is:

> ORDER BY forum_categorieen.categorie_naam ASC");

Coding

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT forum_categorieen.*, gebruikers.username
                     FROM forum_categorieen
                     LEFT JOIN gebruikers
                     ON forum_categorieen.laatste_user_id = gebruikers.user_id
                     ORDER BY forum_categorieen.categorie_naam ASC");
```

Comment: Have you read the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to see the syntax for mysqli_query()?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're passing the wrong parameters to the [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function.

This function expects the first parameter to be the result of [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) (A link identifier) since you must establish a connection to your MySQL server before trying to run queries against it and a second parameter which would be your SQL query.

Once fixed your code will look something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$query = mysqli_query($link, 
                    "SELECT forum_categorieen.*, gebruikers.username
                     FROM forum_categorieen
                     LEFT JOIN gebruikers
                     ON forum_categorieen.laatste_user_id = gebruikers.user_id
                     ORDER BY forum_categorieen.categorie_naam ASC");
```